# Splitting a string according to a delimiter when elements in the string can contain the delimiter

Tags: regex, split

I have a string that looks like this:

`"#Text() #SomeMoreText() #TextThatContainsDelimiter(#blah) #SomethingElse()"`

I'd like to get back

`[#Text(), #SomeMoreText(), #TextThatContainsDelimiter(#blah), #SomethingElse()]`

One way I thought about doing this was to require that the `#` to be escaped into `\#`, which makes the input string:

`"#Text() #SomeMoreText() #TextThatContainsDelimiter(\#blah) #SomethingElse()"`

I can then split it using `/[^\\]#/` which gives me:

`[#Text(), SomeMoreText, TextThatContainsDelimiter(\#blah), SomethingElse()]`

The first element will contain `#` but I can strip it out. However, is there a cleaner way to do this without having to escape the `#`, and which ensures that the first element will not contain a `#`? Basically I'd like it to split by `#` only if the `#` is not enclosed by parentheses.

My hunch is that since the `#` is context-sensitive and and regular expressions are only suited for context-free strings, this may not be the right tool. If so, would I have to write a grammar for this and roll my own parser/lexer?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't even suitable for context-free grammars. Just think about why they might be named *regular* expressions ;-)

Comment: Hmm... good point. I need to go back and read my computing-theory textbooks again :)

Comment: The part that is not regular is the parenthesis matching. If you need to match arbitrarily-nested parentheses (which is what you've asked), you need something stronger.

Comment: The only thing “stronger” you need is **modern patterns**, which include recursion.  Perl, PCRE, and PHP all support such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it looks like you want to split on whitespace that's immediately followed by a hash symbol:

```
/\s+(?=#)/
```

That leaves the leading `#` on all the tokens, but you won't need to treat the first token specially.  You could also use this:

```
/(?:^|\s+)#/
```

That would strip the hash symbols at the cost of generating an empty string as the first token.  But some languages provide a way to discard empty leading tokens.  Note that JavaScript *does* support lookaheads, just not lookbehinds.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Argh! I tend to lose my abilities here. The regex `(?<!\()(?=#)` works

```
PS Home:\> $s -split '(?<!\()(?=#)'

#Text()
#SomeMoreText()
#TextThatContainsDelimiter(#blah)
#SomethingElse()
```

This combines a *negative lookbehind* (to make sure there isn't an opening parenthesis preceding the `#`) and a *positive lookahead* to look for the `#`.

Comment: Interesting! This works for the example, but let's say I have the following: #Text(/#blah/). It fails there (splits along / so that we get #Text(, #blah/)). I'm reasonably well-versed in regexes, but obviously nowhere near your level. Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: Not really, no. As I said, I don't understand this either. `(?!<\()(?=#))` would have been straightforward ... it would match between the `#` and the preceding character (provided said character isn't an opening parenthesis). But doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: So I've determined that if the # inside the parentheses is preceded by a /, it is split along the / (and the / goes missing). I read up a little more on regular expressions and figured out that you are using a negative-lookahead and a positive-lookahead. Trying to figure out how your first negative-lookahead works :)

Comment: @Vivin: Ok, found my mistake and corrected it. The first one was supposed to be a look*behind*.

Comment: Perfect! That works in my perl script. I tried to do this in Javascript, but it doesn't support any form of look-behind :( Thanks!